# How can I test if a particular exception is not thrown?

Tags: junit

Can I test whether a particular Exception is **not** thrown?

The other way round is easy using `@Test[expect=MyException]`.

But how can I negate this?

Comment: This will test, that the exception is thrown. It will fail if the exception is not thrown. So it already does what you want (?)

Comment: Your title (both before and after editing) contradict your question's text. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, i ment how can i test if a particular Exception is not thrown

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test that no exception is thrown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731234/how-to-test-that-no-exception-is-thrown)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to test if a particular Exception is *not* thrown in a condition where *other* exceptions could be thrown, try this:

```
try {
  myMethod();
}
catch (ExceptionNotToThrow entt){
  fail("WHOOPS! Threw ExceptionNotToThrow" + entt.toString);
}
catch (Throwable t){
  //do nothing since other exceptions are OK
}
assertTrue(somethingElse);
//done!
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following using [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html)

if you want to check if exception is not thrown then

```
Throwable throwable = catchThrowable(() -> sut.method());

assertThat(throwable).isNull();
```

or you expect to throw

```
Throwable throwable = catchThrowable(() -> sut.method());

assertThat(throwable).isInstanceOf(ClassOfExecption.class)
                     .hasMessageContaining("expected message");
```

Answer (score 3):

[catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/)  makes the example of Freiheit a bit more concise:

```
catchException(a).myMethod();
assertFalse(caughtException() instanceof ExceptionNotToThrow);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another latest solution could be using Junit5 [assertDoesNotThrow](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertDoesNotThrow(org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable,java.lang.String)):

```
assertDoesNotThrow( () -> myMethod() , "MyException is not thrown")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Test(expected = Test.None::class)` (in Kotlin)