# Can we verify, no excpetion occured in a method from unit testing

Tags: java, junit

> ATest.java -
>   Can we verify, when no exception occurred in a testdisplay2() method like we use expected  when some exception occurred in testdisplay1()

```
class A{
  public void display(){
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if(a){
     throw new AIsTrueException("a true");
    }

    if(b){
     throw new BIsTrueException("b true");
    }

  }
}

class BTest{
...
@InjectMock
A subject;
...
@Test(expected=AIsTrueException.class)
public void testdisplay1(){
    subject.display(true,false);
}

@Test
public void testdisplay2(){
    subject.display(false,false);
    // Here how can I verify that no exception has occured in display(),
    // (When exception occured we use expected = ...)
    // Do we have similar when no exception occured
} 
...
...
}
```

Comment: If an exception ocurred that shouldn't have happened, the test will fail in itself

Comment: you could change the return type of the display method to an int or something which will only be returned if no exception was thrown and check if the retuned value exists

Comment: You may rename your test method to convey the expected behavior, e.g.: `displayDoesNotThrowExceptionWhenBothParametersAreFalse()`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yes if I change the return type then I can use assert the return value. But here the return type is void that I can not change. Is there anyway, I can test that the particular exception does not occurred.

Comment: you can try `expected!=AIsTrueException.class||BIsTrueException.class` never tried it myself. might work

Comment: No we can't do that..

Answer (score 1):

What you have is correct. Try changing `display()` to always throw an `AIsTrueException` and you will see that `testdisplay2()` gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

The expected behaviour is that *no* exception will be thrown. If any is thrown the test will fail unless there is an `expected` parameter in the annotation like the one you have in the `testdisplay1` test.

Also, this is a nice read: [How to test that no exception is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731234/how-to-test-that-no-exception-is-thrown)

Comment: Yes if any exception is thrown... we use expected. But here I want to verify that no exception is thrown from the method.

Comment: well, if there is any exception being thrown the test will fail. So, if the test succeeds it means that NO exception was thrown.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But can't we have any way to verify that using some code.

Comment: Anyways thank you..  I will go with that, If tests succeeds... no exception is thrown..