# How to Assert No exception thrown TestNG java

Tags: java, testng

Hey All I have a question that I try to resolve.
I am using selenium with pure java and test NG.
In the test class I want to call a method and if the method throw exception I want to fail the test.
this is the method:

```
public  void insertAddress2(String address2) throws Exception {}
```

and i want to call it from a test class, and if it (the insert address2 method)  throw exception I want the test to fail.

this is the the class test  Assertion statement

```
@Test(groups = {"address"},enabled = true)
public void testAddress() throws Exception {
Assert.assertNotEquals(adderess.insertAddress2("test"),ErrorMessagePermission, "");
}
```

can someone please advise what is the syntax and how to test not exception thrown in the insertAddress2 method from different class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test that no exception is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731234/how-to-test-that-no-exception-is-thrown)

Comment: I believe the same applies to testNG and selenium

Answer (score 1):

Basically, even in tests, when you want to react on exceptions, you would have to catch them:

```java
@Test(groups = {"address"}, enabled = true)
public void testAddress() { //no throws decleration required
    try {
        adderess.insertAddress2("test");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Assert.fail("Exception was thrown!");
    }
}
```